# Play 2.4 Global settings

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I have global object in the root of app folder. But methods onStart and onStop do not work. What is wrong and how can I fix it ?

```
import persistence.Persist
import play.api._

object Glabal extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    try {
      Persist.createSchema
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Logger.info("Schema exists", e)
    }
    Logger.info("Application has started")
  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
  }
}
```

BR!

Comment: You should read [Removing `GlobalSettings`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings) from the migration guide

Answer (score 1):

it should work exactly, how you did it.
But: You do have a "typo":
Your object is named "Glabal", instead of "Global".